# Bezel swiping in viewpager

Tags: android

I am trying to implement bezel swipe in a viewpager which has 5 pages. I tried implementing OnGestureListener onFling method, but when I try Swiping from left edge of the screen to execute bezel swipe which should be showing sidemenu, instead nothing happens.

This is my current implementation

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, 
                       float velocityY)
{
    Log.e("Event", "onFling");

    if( e1.getX() < 5.0f )
    {
        Log.e("Event", "Bezel swipe!");
    }
    return false; 
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: what do you have so far? example: http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/  specific activity class http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/trunk/AwesomePager/src/com/geekyouup/paug/awesomepager/AwesomePagerActivity.java

Comment: And when you post your attempt, please also explain what "not working" means exactly (exception? compile time error? something else?).

Comment: Without seeing any code, I don't think anyone can help. Are you sure there are no exceptions being thrown on the log-cat?